# Deserializing JSON collection in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

This is a JSON message I get from server (which I can't change). There might be many more objects (time / value) returned, but in this case there is only one. The format stays the same regardless.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-12T13:52:43",
      "value": 255.0
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON to a very simple C# object.

```
public class Dataentry {
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried deserialization with Newtonsoft's JSON.Net and RestSharp libraries with no success. The following code doesn't work, but neither does anything else I've tried :-) I get no error -- just an empty object with default initial values.

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dataentry> (jsonString);
```

Since those libraries are not very intuitive or well documented in this kind of case, I'm lost. Is this kind of JSON impossible to deserialize? I really would like to use a ready-made library, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On the contrary, I find `json.net` has a very good documentation. You just don't understand `JSON` syntax ;-] and that's why you didn't know what to expect from it ;-]

Comment: You're right that I don't understand the issue completely - that's why I have problems :-) Especially in json.net there is a lot of documentation and that is great. But it is based on what library does - not so much how to use it. I think this is a general problem in any library. Documentation is usually written to be a reference guide when you know what you are doing. Beginners need more of use-cased -based / getting started kinds of stuff.

Comment: If you don't mind and any of the answers solved your problem it would be nice if you picked the one that helped you so that everyone knows it's solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not working because your JSON is specifying a collection and you are trying to deseralize into one object.  There are plenty of json to c# class generators you can paste json into to get an appropriate class definition(s) one such generator is located [here](http://json2csharp.com/)

A more appropriate definition would be

```
public class Datum
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then deseralize as

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (jsonString);
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Problem solved! That is an easy way to create classes and good thing to know in future. Tools beat the ignorance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like add some extra explanetion to your question...

You write *I'm trying to deserialize the JSON to a very simple C# object.* - unfortunatelly this is not the complete truth. What you are trying is to deserialize a collection of a very simple C# objects. The indicator for this are the square brackets in your json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-12T13:52:43",
      "value": 255.0
    }
  ]
}
```

It means that there is a class with a property *named* `data` (it can ba mapped to some other name but for the sake of simplicity let's stick to this name) and that this property is a collection type. It can be one of any types that support the `IEnumerable` interface.

```
public class DataCollection
{
    public DataItem[] data { get; set; }
    //public List<DataItem> data { get; set; } // This would also work.
    //public HashSet<DataItem> data { get; set; } // This would work too.
}

public class DataItem
{
    public float value { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; } // This would work because the time is in an ISO format I believe so json.net can parse it into DateTime.
}
```

The next step is to tell Json.Net how to deserialize it. Now when you know it's a complex data type you can use the type that describes the json structure for deserialization:

```
var dataCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataCollection>(jsonString);
```

If you didn't have the `data` property in you json string but something like this:

```
[
    {
      "time": "2014-12-12T13:52:43",
      "value": 255.0
    },
    {
      "time": "2016-12-12T13:52:43",
      "value": 25.0
    },
]
```

you could directly deserialize it as a collection:

```
var dataItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataItem>>(jsonString);
```

or

```
var dataItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataItem[]>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This was very useful. The structure of JSON got me lost (it seems strangely complicated) but this helped me understand why it was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your DateEntry binding Definition

```
public class ArrayData{
    public DataEntry data {set; get;}
}

public class DataEntry {
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

in your method now you  can received an ArraData Object

be careful with datetime string values sent for correct binding